# Graph API use the search API with a managed identity

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I might want to run a query against Graph API from a Logic App to search sharepoint for URLs, to do so I want to use a system-assigned identity, which will be given permissions to query sharepoint.

However, when I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0 it explicitly says:

'Search requests run in the context of the signed-in user, identified using an access token with delegated permissions.'

While I have the idea that the managed identity will have application permissions and not delegated permissions. Does this mean that the managed identity will not be able to use this endpoint at all? Or is this wrongly documented?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, You need to use delegated permissions for that API managed identity will not work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/calling-graph-api-from-azure-logic-apps-using-delegated/ba-p/1997666